# Can't shift+select in Finder in Lion 10.7.1

Tags: finder, keyboard

In previous versions of Mac OS X, to select a whole row of files, you select the file which comes first in the row and then select the last file with a shift+click.

When I try this procedure **in icon view** in Lion, it behaves as if I would select the files separately.

What changed? Is there a way to restore the old behavior?

Comment: In the Finder? Do you have a special shortcut configuration? Special customization? I cannot reproduce the problem in Lion.

Comment: Do you mean on the desktop, or in a window? For me, it selects all between in a window, but only the items I click on the desktop.

Comment: For reproduction try to view items in icon view and then shift+select them, it won't work. The only walk around is to use an other view than icon view. Is this a bug or a feature? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Seems to be a feature when you try to shift+select files in icon view